# Is Elu int8 quantisation working on Tensorflow Lite?

Tags: tensorflow, arduino, tensorflow-lite, quantization

*Context* :
I would like to run inferencing of a DL-model on an Arduino and, since I don't have much memory available, I need to post-training **int8-quantize** my model.
But the **quantization** of my model **doesn't seem to be working**, and it seems to be linked to the **Elu activations functions** in the model.
Indeed, I get **no error** during both the conversion and the quantization of the model on Python and the inferencing on Arduino, but **the necessary size for the model on the Arduino remains the same than without quantization**.

*What I tried* :

- I retrained a model in which I changed the Elu for **Relu** activation functions. Then quantization **works** : thanks to the line : `tflInterpreter->arena_used_bytes()` on Arduino, I can see that quantization helped me to reduce the necessary size for the model **by 3**.
- I analysed the model (quantized, with Elu) on the Netron App and I realised that there are steps of **de-quantization and re-quantization** before and after each call of Elu function : [model de-quantize and re-quantize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8ECt.png). I don't understand why is this doing so, when it doesn't append with Relu functions.
- Finally, I found this commit on Tensorflow Git, which made me believe that int8 quantization for Elu **is implemented** : [Commit for Elu int8 quantization TF](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/918f876bf812fd744151fea29b2df4aa18acfa8f). Nevertheless, they mentioned a LUT approach, which I don't understand and might (?) be linked to the troubles I am facing.

*Context* :

- TF 2.5.
- Training, conversion and quantisation on Colab
- Arduino with TFLite version 2.5

Does anyone face the same king of troubles for quantization of model containing Elu ? Do you have any idea of how to solve this problem ?

Thank you really much !

Comment: Hi, thanks for catching! I've patched and hopefully it should work on nightly.

Comment: This problem has been solved thanks to a change in the codebase of TensorFlow. Elu quantization is working now ! Thanks !